# Have there been any reconstructive efforts of proto-languages, where aspects of historic culture have been inferred for languages other than PIE?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, sociolinguistics

I'm not sure if this is the right SE to ask this question (possibly History SE?), but here goes!

Similar to the source material for [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErXa5PyHj4I), have there been any efforts to infer aspects of culture from reconstructed proto-languages other than PIE? If so, what have we found?

Comment: Proto-Austronesian is one case where a fair amount of work has been done in this area. This kind of work is sometimes called 'culture history'.

Comment: Ah thanks. I find a decent proportion of research time is just finding the right terminology to search by! Will give that a go.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1006619?seq=1)